# How to delete from the database using Ajax with Laravel and Restful Controllers

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have the following code in my view:

```
@foreach ($articlestore as $art)

<form action="{{URL::to('/story/' . $art->id)}}" method="post" id="article_one">

<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" name="chosen_title" value="{{$art->id}}" class="form-control">
</div>
<button type ="button" onclick="deleteArticle({{ $art->id }})" id="Reco">Delete</button>
{{Form::token()}}

</form> 
@endforeach


<script type="text/javascript">

function deleteArticle(id) {

 $.ajax({
 url: '/Project/public/story/'+id,
 data: { "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}" },
 type: 'DELETE',
 success: function(result) {
 console.log(result);
}
});
}
```

Controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{

     $articledel = FootballArticle::find($id);
             $articledel->delete();


}
```

Im very new to AJAX and so im struggling to know how to delete a row from my table using JQuery. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you having? What do you want it to do, and what is it doing?

Comment: Im simply trying to delete an article from my table using Ajax and with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```html
<button type ="button" onclick="deleteArticle($art->id)" id="Reco">Delete</button>
```

to

```html
<button type ="button" onclick="deleteArticle({{ $art->id }})" id="Reco">Delete</button>
                                              ^^          ^^
```

In `deleteArticle()` change

```
url: 'http://localhost/Project/public/story'+id,
```

to

```
url: '/Project/public/story/'+ id,
     ^^                   ^^
```

and add

```
data: { "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}" },
```

so it looks like

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/project/public/story/' + id,
    data: { "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}" },
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Also you don't need to do a redirect in your `destroy()` method when you make an ajax call

```
return Redirect::back();
```

Comment: it's still not deleting. I noticed you missed out the `id` parameter in the `deleteArticle()` function. Do I need it? anyway i've tried with and without

Comment: i followed your method, it's working fine. It seems like the page doesn't refresh. return redirect(); doesn't work properly.